# Non-boolean type specified exception

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

```
con.Open();
string str = "select Email ID,Type from User_Reg where Email ID=@EmailID and password=@password";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str,con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailID", txtemail.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpwd.Text);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
}
```

This is my code in c#. I'm getting this error on `da.fill(dt);`:

```
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'ID'
```

I am using visual studio 2012 with inbuilt sql server 2012.

Comment: `Email ID` should be enclosed in square brackets: `[Email ID]`.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is in the where clause, remove the alias
:

```
select Email ID,Type from User_Reg where Email ID=@EmailID and password=@password
```

should be like this

```
select Email ID,Type from User_Reg where Email=@EmailID and password=@password
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sql statement is false:

WRONG:

string str = "select Email ID,Type from User_Reg where Email ID=@EmailID and password=@password";

TRUE:

string str = "select EmailID,Type from User_Reg where EmailID=@EmailID and password=@password";